# Shortest universal bit string: One string to contain all others

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

Let $s$ be a string of bits. Treat it as a cycle, with the first bit following
the last.
Say that $s$ is *universal for $n$* if all the $2^n$ strings
of $n$ bits can be found in $s$ as consecutive, left-to-right bits
(with wrap-around).
Define $u(n)$ as the length of the shortest string universal for $n$.

*Examples*:

$u(1)=2$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{0} & 1 \\
0 & \color{red}{1}
\end{matrix}
$$

$u(2)=4$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & 1 \\
\color{red}{0} & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{1} \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} 
\end{matrix}
$$

$u(3)=8$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{1} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0}  & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$

> ***Q1***. What is $u(n)$?

This may be simple, but the wrap-around seems to make it not so straightforward.

> ***Q2***. What is the generalization to strings of $k$ symbols?
>   Let $u(k,n)$ be the length of the shortest string on $k$ symbols
>   that contains all strings of length $n$.

Likely this is all known...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is related to [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). The formula seems to be *very* simple: $u(k,n) = k^n$ (and the special case $u(n) = 2^n$).
[image]

<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#/media/File:De_Bruijn_sequence.svg), by Eviatar Bach)</sub>

Comment: Perfect---Thanks!